# How to convert this my code into a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, list-comprehension

I've written this code so that it generates 4 random ints ranging from 1-6 and then remove the smallest number and add it to a list that is returned.

I was reading around and found that list comprehensions are the more "pythonic" solution instead of these small for range loops. I would like to know how to write this code as a list comprehension and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
stats = []

for stat in range(6):
    score = [random.randint(1, 6) for n in range(4)]
    score.remove(min(score))
    stats.append(sum(score))

return stats
```

Comment: keep this code it will be more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3.7 or less, you can do this using the following combination of list comprehensions + generator expression:

```
stats = [sum(score) - min(score) for score in ([random.randint(1, 6) for n in range(4)] for stat in range(6))]
```

In Python 3.8 (still in beta), you can do it in a simpler way thanks to the new [`walrus`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics) assignment operator:

```
stats = [sum(score := [random.randint(1, 6) for n in range(4)]) - min(score) for stat in range(6)]
```

You can try it [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP5eruCSxpFjBViG6uDRXozg5vyhVwQrIg8jqgajMvBINQx0FM02FtPwihTyFzDyQ3vRUDRPNWE0FXYXczDyIRogCkIEINWaasVwFRSAjwBZp/v8PAA).

Testing both approaches:

#### Comprehensions (`<=`Python 3.7):

```
import random

random.seed(1)

stats = [sum(score) - min(score) for score in ([random.randint(1, 6) for n in range(4)] for stat in range(6))]

print(stats)
```

Output:

```
[10, 12, 12, 12, 15, 14]
```

#### Comprehensions + walrus (Python 3.8):

```
import random

random.seed(1)

stats = [sum(score := [random.randint(1, 6) for n in range(4)]) - min(score) for stat in range(6)]

print(stats)
```

Output:

```
[10, 12, 12, 12, 15, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

I define a function to generate score before using the list comprehension.

```
import random
stats = []

def make_rand_score():
    score = [random.randint(1, 6) for n in range(4)]
    score.remove(min(score))
    return score
stats = [make_rand_score() for i in range(5)]

print(stats)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
from random import randint
[min([randint(1, 6) for _ in range(4)]) for _ in range(6)]
```

However this gets a little complex and hard to read so maybe it's not the best solution.